# SQL Server expanding table according to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I had a table like this:

```
Name      Sex    A      B      C

Alice     F      1      2      -
Bob       M      -      3      4
David     M      -      -      5
```

I need to expand the table according to the column keys from 'A' to 'C' (ignoring the null value) as following:

```
Name      Sex   Type   Value

Alice     F      A      1
Alice     F      B      2
Bob       M      B      3
Bob       M      C      4
David     M      C      5
```

How could I build a 'stored procedure' for accomplishing this

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`:

```
select t.name, t.sex, v.type, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values ('A', t.A), ('B', t.B), ('C', t.C)) v(type, value)
where v.value is not null;
```

If you need this done "automatically", then create a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.name, t.sex, v.type, v.value
    from t cross apply
         (values ('A', t.A), ('B', t.B), ('C', t.C)) v(type, value)
    where v.value is not null;
```

There is no need for a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks. Actually there are 80 columns (rather than A,B and C in the demonstration) and I'm not sure if there column names would be changed in the future. Is there any approach that firstly "get all column names except 'name' and 'sex' " and then automatically do the "cross apply" part?

Comment: @MTANG . . . You need to list the column names you want.